# Table with additional conditions for the generated objects

Tags: list-manipulation, map, table

Suppose that I have a function

```
prob[n_] := Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, n}]
```

that generates tuples with n entries that correspond to probabilities. What I would like to do is write a function prob[n_,eps_] that for a given n ≥ 2 and eps (with 0 < eps ≤ 0.10) generates all tuples (including permutations of elements in the tuple) that "differ by eps" (explained below) and satisfy

a) 0 ≤ p_i ≤ 1 for each individual probability in the tuple

b) \sum_i p_i = 1, i.e. the probabilities in the tuple sum to 1

What I mean with "differ by eps" is that, for example, for n=3 and eps=0.10 the list of generated tuples should look like {1,0,0}, {0.9,0.1,0}, {0.9,0,0.1}, {0.8,0.2,0}, {0.8,0.1,0.1},{0.8,0,0.2}, etc.

I suspect that this can be done using another Table[] and/or maybe Map[]. I have tried things like this

```
prob[n_, \[Epsilon]_] := Map[Table[# &, {x, 0, 1, \[Epsilon]}], Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, n}]]
```

but of course here Mathematica does not know what "x" is (and also the sum criterion is not implemented).

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Edit: To clarify what the desired output should be. For n=2, eps=0.1, the function should produce

```
n2out = {{1, 0}, {0.9, 0.1}, {0.8, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.3}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.5,
 0.5}, {0.4, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.9}, {0, 1}};
```

For n=3 and eps=0.1, the function should produce

```
n3out = {{1, 0, 0}, {0.9, 0.1, 0}, {0.9, 0, 0.1}, {0.8, 0.2, 0}, {0.8,
 0.1, 0.1}, {0.8, 0, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.3, 0}, {0.7, 0.2, 0.1}, {0.7, 
0.1, 0.2}, {0.7, 0, 0.3}, {0.6, 0.4, 0}, {0.6, 0.3, 0.1}, {0.6, 
0.2, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.1, 0.3}, {0.6, 0, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.5, 0}, {0.5, 
0.4, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.1, 
0.4}, {0.5, 0, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.6, 0}, {0.4, 0.5, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.4, 
0.2}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.1, 0.5}, {0.4, 0, 
0.6}, {0.3, 0.7, 0}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.4, 
0.3}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.6}, {0.3, 0, 
0.7}, {0.2, 0.8, 0}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.5, 
0.3}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 
0.1, 0.7}, {0.2, 0, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.9, 0}, {0.1, 0.8, 0.1}, {0.1, 
0.7, 0.2}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.4, 
0.5}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.8}, {0.1, 0, 
0.9}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0.9, 0.1}, {0, 0.8, 0.2}, {0, 0.7, 0.3}, {0, 
0.6, 0.4}, {0, 0.5, 0.5}, {0, 0.4, 0.6}, {0, 0.3, 0.7}, {0, 0.2, 
0.8}, {0, 0.1, 0.9}, {0, 0, 1}};
```

The answer provided by lericr seems to do the trick, but if there are other (possibly more convenient) ways of doing it I'd still be very keen to hear about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we make the simplifying assumption that `eps` is of the form `1/n` for some integer `n`, then we can re-conceive of the problem as integer partitions of `n` (which we then re-scale).

```
prob[count_, scale_Integer?Positive] := 
  Catenate[Permutations[PadRight[#, count]] & /@ IntegerPartitions[scale, count]]/scale
```

Usage:

```
prob[3, 10]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, ..., {3/10, 2/5, 3/10}, {3/10, 3/10, 2/5}} *)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand correctly what you want.

First we must round 1/n to get an integer: no. Then we can use "IntegerPartitions" to get n-tuples that sum to no. Then we take all permutations of these tuples. Finally we divide by no:

```
prob[n_, eps_] := Module[{no = Round[1/eps]},
  t = Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[no, {3}];
  t = Flatten[t, 1];
  t/no // N
  ]
```

Here is a test of this:

```
prob[3, 0.1]

{{0.8, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.8, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.8}, {0.7, 0.2, 
  0.1}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.1, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.7, 
  0.2}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.3, 0.1}, {0.6, 0.1, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.6, 
  0.1}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.6}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.3}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.6, 0.2, 
  0.2}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6}, {0.5, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.1, 
  0.4}, {0.4, 0.5, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5, 0.4}, {0.1, 0.4, 
  0.5}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2, 
  0.5}, {0.2, 0.5, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 0.2, 
  0.4}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.4, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.3, 
  0.4}}
```

**Addendum**

To include entries like {1,0,0} and {0.9,0.1,0} we need to change "IntegerPartition":

```
prob[n_, eps_] := 
 Module[{no = Round[1/eps]},  
  t = Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[no, {3}, Range[0, no]];
  t = Flatten[t, 1];
  t/no // N]

prob[3, 0.1]

{{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}, {0.9, 0.1, 0.}, {0.9, 0., 
  0.1}, {0.1, 0.9, 0.}, {0.1, 0., 0.9}, {0., 0.9, 0.1}, {0., 0.1, 
  0.9}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.}, {0.8, 0., 0.2}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.}, {0.2, 0., 
  0.8}, {0., 0.8, 0.2}, {0., 0.2, 0.8}, {0.8, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.8, 
  0.1}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.8}, {0.7, 0.3, 0.}, {0.7, 0., 0.3}, {0.3, 0.7, 
  0.}, {0.3, 0., 0.7}, {0., 0.7, 0.3}, {0., 0.3, 0.7}, {0.7, 0.2, 
  0.1}, {0.7, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.2, 0.1, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.7, 
  0.2}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.}, {0.6, 0., 0.4}, {0.4, 0.6, 
  0.}, {0.4, 0., 0.6}, {0., 0.6, 0.4}, {0., 0.4, 0.6}, {0.6, 0.3, 
  0.1}, {0.6, 0.1, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.1}, {0.3, 0.1, 0.6}, {0.1, 0.6, 
  0.3}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.6}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2, 
  0.6}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.}, {0.5, 0., 0.5}, {0., 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.4, 
  0.1}, {0.5, 0.1, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.5, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5, 
  0.4}, {0.1, 0.4, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.2}, {0.5, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.5, 
  0.2}, {0.3, 0.2, 0.5}, {0.2, 0.5, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.4, 
  0.2}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.4, 
  0.3}, {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I was looking for. For example, this list does not include entries of the form {1,0.9,0},{1,0,0.9}, etc.; I've edited my original post to clarify the desired output. I will play around with the suggestions provided here some more, but it seems that the solution provided by lericr does exactly that.

Comment: I added a part that includes tuples like {1,0,0}, {0.9,0.1,0}..

Comment: Thanks! This works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`FrobeniusSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html)

```
prb[n_, eps_] := N @ eps  FrobeniusSolve[Table[1, n], Ceiling[1/eps]]

prb[2, .1]
```

> ```
> {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 0.9}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.4, 0.6},   
>  {0.5, 0.5}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.7, 0.3}, {0.8, 0.2}, {0.9, 0.1}, {1., 0.}}
> ```

```
prb[2, .2]
```

> ```
> {{0., 1.}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.4, 0.6}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.2}, {1., 0.}}
> ```

```
prb[3, .2]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0., 1.}, {0., 0.2, 0.8}, {0., 0.4, 0.6}, {0., 0.6, 0.4},   
>  {0., 0.8, 0.2}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0.2, 0., 0.8}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6},   
>  {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.},   
>  {0.4, 0., 0.6}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2},   
>  {0.4, 0.6, 0.}, {0.6, 0., 0.4}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.},  
>  {0.8, 0., 0.2}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.}, {1., 0., 0.}}
> ```

#### IntegerPartitions + Permutations

```
prb2[n_, eps_] := Module[{m = Round[1/eps]}, 
  eps  Apply[Join] @ Map[Permutations] @ IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Range[0, m]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
prb2[2, .2]
```

> ```
>  {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}, {0.8, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.6}}
> ```

```
prb2[2, .1]
```

> ```
>  {{1., 0.}, {0., 1.}, {0.9, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.9}, {0.8, 0.2},  
>   {0.2, 0.8}, {0.7, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.6}, {0.5, 0.5}}
> ```

```
prb2[3, .2]
```

> ```
>  {{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}, {0.8, 0.2, 0.},  
>   {0.8, 0., 0.2}, {0.2, 0.8, 0.}, {0.2, 0., 0.8},   
>   {0., 0.8, 0.2}, {0., 0.2, 0.8}, {0.6, 0.4, 0.},   
>   {0.6, 0., 0.4}, {0.4, 0.6, 0.}, {0.4, 0., 0.6},   
>   {0., 0.6, 0.4}, {0., 0.4, 0.6}, {0.6, 0.2, 0.2},   
>   {0.2, 0.6, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.6}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.2},   
>   {0.4, 0.2, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.4}}
> ```

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you!